# Change the $( function() ) name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie with J Query ...

I copied a script for scrolling image horizontally. It work fine and calls the function:

```
$(function())
```

to perform that task. There is  another implementation for a vertical scrolling element. But it uses the same call

```
$(function())
```

How can I combine both functions in the same html page ? Is it possible to change the name function() as something else ? If yes, how ? It not works (at least in my hands...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$(function(){})` is just a [shorthand](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for vanilla JS's `onload` event so you could, if necessary do

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // Code here is executed when DOM is loaded
})
```